# How to correctly format "&nbsp" in eldoc using eglot

Tags: eglot, eldoc

I'm using eglot with the pyright language server protocol. When I look at the documentation for numpy, for example, I see a lot of "&nbsp" in the documentation. I have installed the `markdown-mode` but the problem persists. How can I get whitespace to show up correctly?

[image]